# passive ambiguity in this sentence

Tags: relative-clauses, passive-voice

> そう言って今度は頭を下げられる俺。
>
> After saying that, she directs a bow at me.

the other party is making a request so there is no doubt in context who is bowing.

In isolation i find rearanging this relative clause somewhat ambigious.

- (彼女に)俺(に/へ？)頭を下げられる
- 俺に頭を下げられる

Are any of these explicilty incorrent?

Comment: Is this passive or potential? Where did you get your translation from? Source please.

Comment: can't really see how potential would fit here, the speaker is talking to a girl that is asking him to stay away from her friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ｛頭を下げられる｝俺

頭を下げられる is a relative clause modifying 俺, so rearranging it to a normal word order...

> 俺が（彼女に）頭を下げられる。 I am bowed to (by her)

This is passive, so turning it to the active voice..

> 彼女が俺に頭を下げる。 She bows to me / She begs me

Cf.
｛頼まれる｝俺
→俺が（彼女に）頼まれる  I am asked (by her)
→彼女が俺に頼む She asks me